# Not able to render partial with Gmaps4Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, gmaps4rails

I have a map which has got marker based on state of US. Each state has n number of city.

I have got a state model, controller and city model, controller.

When I click on the marker of the state, I want the list of cities to be displayed in the info window.

All this information is appearing on the homepage.

This is what I have done so far :-

home_controller.rb

```
def index
    @states = State.all.to_gmaps4rails do |state,marker|
        marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/states/gmaps4rails_infowindow", :locals => {:object => state})
        marker.json({:id => state.id})
    end
end
```

home/index.html.haml

```
=gmaps({"map_options" =>{ "auto_zoom" => false, "zoom" => 3}, "markers" => { "data" => @states } })
```

state_controller.rb

```
def gmaps4rails_infowindow
  @state = Gmaps.map.markers
end
```

states/_gmaps4rails_infowindow.html.haml

```
=@state.cities.each do |city|
    =city.name
```

Needless to say that it is not working. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your `home_controller.rb` is fine. you write here you want to use a partial with a local variable named `object`.

In the partial itself, you write:

```
=@state.cities.each do |city|
  =city.name
```

The instance variable isn't defined there, you defined a local variable just above.

Replace with:

```
=object.cities.each do |city|
  =city.name
```

From there it should work.

---

Notice:

```
def gmaps4rails_infowindow
  @state = Gmaps.map.markers 
end
```

is:

- useless: you define the infowindow in the controller
- wrong: `Gmaps.map.markers` only lives as js variable

Comment: thanks it works great :), I will be bugging you in the coming days as I am using your gem for one of my app

Comment: because it's the name YOU gave to the local variable in the partial.

Comment: I get that but but my question was why is it that we have to give the name object?

Comment: call it `barbara` if you prefer :) was just an example